Can I use Prime Number Theorem here?
I found this question in Problem link and was trying to solve this since many days.
Let there be functions $f(N)$ = no. of primes $\leq N$ and $g(N)=\int_{2}^{N}\frac{dx}{\ln x}$
Find the value of $\lfloor g(10^{22})−f(10^{22}) \rfloor$.
My attempt:
I tried to use the Prime Number Theorem but I don't know how large the number must be to use this to get the exact value of $f(N)$. I know that this might be wrong but I can't think of anything else. Any hint?

The logarithmic integral will typically never give you the exact value of $f(N) $, no matter how large $N$ is. I don't see any simple way to compute the answer other than computing $f(10^{22})$ and $g(10^{22})$ exactly.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Table_of_π(x),x/_log_x,_and_li(x) contains the answer

does not seem to be approachable by hand

You’ve asked to find $\left\lfloor\operatorname{li}(10^{22})-\pi(10^{22})\right\rfloor$. You can find $\pi(10^{22})$ as A006880(22) = 201467286689315906290. You can find $\operatorname{li}(10^{22})$ = 201467286691248261498.1… using PARI/GP online with the code
real(-eint1(-log(1e22)))

You can then do the subtraction and rounding (possibly with PARI/GP).

I think we need to find $g(N) = Li(N) = li(N)-li(2)$ then shouldn't the answer be $\lfloor li(10^{22})-li(2)−f(10^{22}) \rfloor$? And wolfram alpha says $li(2) = 1.04516$. Please see that here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2Clnx%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C2%7D%5D.

@NagaSaiPrajith Ok, sounds like you have what you need!

But the website says the answer is incorrect. Also checked for calculation mistakes. There are none.
